# Rich Text Editor Cursor doesn't move making the text be typed backwards

Tags: reactjs, redux, rte

I have a RTE inside a react functional component and for some reason the cursor has stopped moving ahead as the text is typed causing the text to be typed backwards.
Now, I have figured where the issue is but I don't have a solution. I did find [this](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte/issues/242) issue that has the same problem which they fixed with adding `setContentFromString(nextProps.value)` when updating the state but I get the following error

```
TypeError: react_rte__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default.a.setContentFromString is not a function
```

Here is my component.

```
   export default props => {
        const { value, onChange, error, row, readOnly, className, ...rest } = props;
        const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = React.useState(
            value ? RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(unescape(value), 'html') : RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue()
        );
    
        React.useEffect(() => {
            setInternalValue(
                value ? RichTextEditor.createValueFromString(unescape(value), 'html') : RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue()
            );
        }, [value]);
    
        const classes = useStyles({ row });

// the problem area
        function change(value) {
            setInternalValue(value);
            if (onChange) {
                const trimmed = value.toString('markdown').trim();
                if (trimmed.length === 0 || (trimmed.length === 1 && trimmed.charCodeAt(0) === 8203)) {
                    onChange(null);
                } else onChange(escape(value.toString('html')));
            }
        }
    
        return (
            <RichTextEditor
                customStyleMap={customStyles}
                toolbarConfig={toolbarConfig}
                value={internalValue}
                onChange={change}
                readOnly={readOnly}
                toolbarClassName={classes.toolbar}
                editorClassName={clsx(readOnly ? null : classes.editor, error ? classes.error : null)}
                className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
                {...rest}
            />
        );
    };
```

Comment: I think because you update internalValue with value from value and when you have onChange you also update the value. if you comment out the useEffect you can test if my hypothesis is correct

Comment: @ducmai commenting out useEffect does solve the cursor problem but it brings another one. I have a button which populates the editor field from an existing value ( kind of like a template) so if i remove useffect the editor isnt populated with that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `internalValue` was accidentally set to a value that was changing with every keystroke hence triggering the `useEffect` and eventually setting the cursor to position 1.
By using `React.useRef` I was able to compare the changes and get this working.